# Right most edge of a rectangle? What is that? I don't need the code just an understanding of what to do?

Tags: python

Right most edge of a rectangle? What is that? I don't need the code just an understanding of what to do?
I am not familiar with this...

```
Create a method called ``right`` that gets the value of the right edge of the rectangle.     
It should take no arguments:   
>>> r3 = Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20)
>>> r3.right()
    13     


>>> r4 = Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35)
>>> r4.right()
    84
```

my code:

```
class Rectangle:

def __init__(self, rX, rY, rW, rH):
    self.x = rX
    self.y = rY
    self.w = rW
    self.h = rH

def __str__(self):
    return 'Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')'


r = Rectangle(2, 3, 4, 5)
print(str(r))
```

Comment: I think it just means the x-coordinate of the right edge.  rX is the x-coordinate of the left edge.  rW is the width of the rectangle.

Comment: What point on the rectangle do your `rX`, `rY` arguments specify? How do you get from that point to the edge on the right hand side of the rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r3 = Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20)
```

I'm assuming it's (xBase, yBase, xSize, ySize) from your example?

Then the right() is simply xBase + xSize
Similar for bottom().  left() is xBase.

Comment: Hahah okay I knew I was over thinking this I should have looked at the numbers a bit more thanks!

Comment: So the bottom would be yBase and Ysize? Or am I still dense?

Comment: @TYPKRFT: Well, that depends on whether the initial coordinate you give when creating the rectangle is the top-left or bottom-left corner. The most common thing I've seen is the top-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the x coordinate of the right edge of the rectangle. Assuming the x and y coordinate values stored in rectangle instances are that of the upper or lower left coordinate of its corner, it would be that value plus the width value:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, rX, rY, rW, rH):
        self.x = rX
        self.y = rY
        self.w = rW
        self.h = rH

    def right(self):
            return self.x + self.w

    def __str__(self):
        return('Rectangle(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ','
                            + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h)+')')

print(Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20).right())  # 13
print(Rectangle(12, 10, 72, 35).right())  # 84
```

Comment: The bottom would then be rY and rH ?

Comment: @TYPKRFT: The bottom would be either `self.y` if the rX and rY coordinate values are the lower left or right corner, or `self.y - self.h` if they're the upper left or right corner.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means the x coordinate of the rightmost edge of the rectangle, which is in this case rX+rW.

> > > r3 = Rectangle(3, 5, 10, 20)

r3.right() will return 3+10 = 13